# How to configure RubyMine to use remote Git executable?

Tags: ruby, git, configuration, rubymine

I have Windows on my host machine and guest Ubuntu server on VirtualBox. Project code is located on guest and RubyMine is on host. I have configured remote Ruby SDK and shared the project folder. This works good. Now I need to configure Git. Right now it runs local (host) executable. I want to run Git on guest over SSH. It allows to setup only local path (Settings > Version Control > Git).

Any idea how to integrate remote Git executable to be used by RubyMine?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to use remote executable for Git. RubyMine version control integration supports only local git installation.

Comment: Then it can be considered not fully functional remote SDK, isn't it? I'm looking for a way to avoid the requirement to install a version control client on the host machine.
Maybe there are some plugins exist for this purpose? Or I should submit this as a feature request to RubyMine dev team?

Comment: Remote SDK has no relation to the version control integration. You can submit a request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA but I doubt that it will be implemented in the nearest future.